# C# - Reader in SQL always returns false

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

So im trying to make a login system in a C# application and I use sql/mysql for the database in which i store users data and I've came into an error were when im executing the reader, and then im making and if statement (if the reader reads then do something) and the if statement always returns false, i dont know why, it doesnt give any exceptions, I've putten it in a try statement but again no exceptions so really i dont know what is wrong. And also the connections, query and everything is okay (I've double checked it) Here's my code:

```
if (!OpenConnection(Connection)) return false;
                    using (var cmd =
                    new MySqlCommand(
                        "SELECT Login, Password, HWID, Premium, IP FROM Users WHERE Login = @Login AND Password = @Password" +
                        " AND HWID = @HWID AND Premium = @Premium AND IP = @IP",
                        Connection))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", username);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password",
                        Encryption.Encrypt(password, Encryption.RandomBytes().ToString(), salt));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HWID", hardware);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Premium", 1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IP", Helpers.GetIpAddress());

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // < executing the reader everything is ok

if (reader.Read()) // < and then this is where it always returns false no matter what
    {
reader.Close();
Connection.Close();
return true
    }

reader.Close(); // this is where it goes when the reader is returning false
Connection.Close(); // this is where it goes when the reader is returning false
return false; // this is where it goes when the reader is returning false
```

Comment: A `DataReader.Read` returning false means that there are no more rows available from the query result set, which means that the query returned no results. Look at the `WHERE` clause and see if each and every condition fulfills with the current data in the DB.

Comment: Can you verify that your Encryption is returning the exact same results every time? All the Read() is saying is there was nothing to read. Your query can look fine, but it's also possible the data going into your query parameters are not what you think. Are you able to trace the query to see what is actually getting executed against the database? My guess is the password is re-encrypting each time and you're getting a different result.

Comment: Put a breakpoint before the ExecuteReader call, then copy out the commandtext and parameters to something like MySqlWorkbench to see if the exact same query returns results there.

Comment: Yep its okay, just checked it

Comment: The encryption is encrypting the clear password the same everytime because of the salt that im getting also from the db

Comment: Passwords should be salted and hashed, not encrypted.  That `Encryption.RandomBytes()` element makes me also think it doesnt do the same thing everytime.

Comment: Encryption.RandomBytes() is the password to encrypt and/or decrypt this

Comment: And it returns exactly the same, just checked it

Comment: @Veruz you can prefix a commenter's name with `@` so it is clearer which comment you are responding to.

Comment: @Uueerdo ok thanks

Comment: Your scheme is suspect:  passwords should be hashed not encrypted.  In that case it is typical to store the salt in the DB and fetch it bad to test a log in.  If your code can generate new salt each time and result in the same output, the salt entropy is very questionable.  `AddWithValue` is also a bad idea and DB objects should always be created used and disposed as needed - reusing connections is not needed